# Статическая картинка звукового сигнала

Tags: c++, аудио

Подскажите, может есть готовое решение на c++, чтоб получить картинку, аналогичной прикрепленной. То есть взять звуковой файл (.wav, .mp3) и получить или сразу изображение, или массив значений, по которым уже самостоятельно отрисовать график зависимости "время-амплитуда". Спасибо!

[image: waveform]

Comment: Для wav легко написать самому - https://audiocoding.ru/articles/2008-05-22-wav-file-structure/

Comment: Спасибо! С wav более-менее ясно. А с mp3 так просто не получиться, как я понимаю? Мне нужна просто картинка для вспомогательных нужд, с самим звуком я работать не буду

Comment: mp3 - упакован, причем может быть весьма сложно упакован, так что с ним я даже не пытался разбираться. А с wav разбирался, когда малой в школе звуки проходил - тут я ему чего только не моделировал - и биения, и интерференцию, и Доплер... :)

Comment: Можно воспользоваться декодером, который есть в Qt:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277132/qt-audio-file-to-wave-like-audacity

Comment: О, спасибо за ссылку. Похоже это то, что нужно. Пойду раскуривать:)

Comment: @gbg , все сработало. Ваш комментарий можно оформить как ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Картинка Ваша не совсем показательна, она стилизована так, что края напоминают сосульки. Тут http://tolmatux.strana.de/player.html увидите традиционную картинку, которая появляется в результате декодирования аудиофайла формата мп3 с помощью WebAudio Api на языке JavaScript.

Comment: Да картинку я взял просто для примера. В итоге у меня получилось неплохо отрисовать с помощью QQuickPaintedItem, который берет данные об амплитуде, полученные от QAudioDecoder